# Docker Swarm JDBC connection

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-swarm

Running a Postgresql DB on a Docker Swarm containing multiple nodes where the Database can be deployed.  Using Docker version 1.12+.

Using a Data container, the Postgresql failover is working nicely.  Now I would like to have a Java client connect to the DB and also survive failover.  How should the JDBC connections be managed here?  Does the connection string change?  Or should it be managed through something like an nginx container running elsewhere?  Is there an example of this available for study anywhere?  Conceptually, I think I get moving this off to another (nginx-like) container, but can't quite grok the details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swarm mode, you get service discovery by DNS name for services in the same overlay network, you don't need to add a proxy layer yourself. The [swam networking docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/) go into detail, but in essence:

```
docker network create -d overlay app-net
docker service create --name app-db --network app-net [etc.]
docker service create --name app-web --network app-net [etc.]
```

Your database server is available by DNS within the network as `app-db`, to any service in the same `app-net` network. So `app-db` is the server name you use in your JDBC connection string. You can have multiple replicas of the Postgres container, or a single container which moves around at failover - the service will always be available at that address.

**But:** I would be cautious about failover with your data container. You have a single container with your database state there; even if your state is in a volume, it won't move around the cluster. So if the node with the data fails, your data container will start somwhere else, but the data won't go with it.

Comment: Thanks - I will try this!   FWIW, at least for now, I have the state in a volumn on an NFS mount that is mounted on all the physical hosts in the swarm.  So the data is moving for all failures, but I am still investigating better ways to do this

Comment: Lots of people are investigating better ways... NFS is a working option though, at the cost of performance. If you could post your volume mapping here, that might be useful for future readers.

Comment: Jdbc with round robin style loadbalancing of the connection might cause some funny behavior. IMHO a better idea is to start a separate master service with 1 node and another slave service with n nodes. If needed you can add another master service for master-master type setups.